# RedHat C compiler does not compile?

Tags: ruby, linux, compiler-errors, centos, redhat

i am sitting since yesterday at the problem ruby to install on my redhat 7 system. I already have gcc cc and g++ installed. Also several restarts have not helped I always get the following errors :

```
[root@ld01 bin]# rbenv install 2.6.1
Downloading ruby-2.6.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.6.1...

BUILD FAILED (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 using ruby-build 20190130-4-g0e33b11)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20190227084942.17275
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20190227084942.17275.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/ruby-build.20190227084942.17275 /usr/bin
/tmp/ruby-build.20190227084942.17275/ruby-2.6.1 /tmp/ruby-build.20190227084942.17275 /usr/bin
checking for ruby... false
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/ruby-build.20190227084942.17275/ruby-2.6.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I think you'll need the config.log but where exactly can I find the log file ?

Comment: The error messages mention `/tmp/ruby-build.20190227084942.17275`, `/tmp/ruby-build.20190227084942.17275.log` and `/tmp/ruby-build.20190227084942.17275/ruby-2.6.1`. Does any of these exist? You might find `config.log` there. Do you need to build `ruby`? Isn't there a ready-made package for your redhat 7 system?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've downloaded Ruby and are trying to install it over an existing version - if so, this can break things.  If Ruby 2.5 will suffice, I suggest using the version available in RHEL as a Software Collection.  Installation info is [here](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world/#fndtn-ruby).

Software Collections alongside the original Ruby version (used by the OS) so that nothing breaks.